# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file on line 162

Tags: php

I'm kinda new to Stack Overflow so please forgive my bad questioning or so...

I'm making a log in system currently but when i test it, i get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/whosa/domains/*****/public_html/feam/index.php on line 164
```

I know that the fault is laying in the PHP, so here is it:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/bootstrap.php');
if (!isLoggedIn())
{
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
        {
header('location: /loggedin.php');
        } else
        {
            echo "<div id='error'>Je gegevens zijn fout!</div>";
        }  


?>
```

Does anyone know who the fault is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you've posted is the complete code, then you're missing two braces to close `if` statements.

```
<?php
require_once('includes/bootstrap.php');
if (!isLoggedIn())
{
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
        {
            header('location: /loggedin.php');
        } else
        {
        echo "<div id='error'>Je gegevens zijn fout!</div>";
        }
    } // HERE
} // AND HERE
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Two of your IF statements aren't closed.

`if (!isLoggedIn())`

and

`if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")`